# How to test a website

Tags: selenium, junit

I've been looking into ways to perform some basic automated tests:

- Does the given page have the expected HTTP status (typically 200)
- Are there any problems with related files (HTTP status on used files such as JS, CSS, images, fonts, ...)
- Are there any JS errors while loading the page

Many of the commonly used tools (such as Selenium) don't seem to support these tests, so I really don't know where to start... Does anyone know a simple solution for covering these tests ?

Comment: That's integration testing and there's no easy solution, have to start climbing.

Comment: I think you probably looking for a web UI testing. We use a selenium based solution and didn't had to go through a steep learning curve.

Comment: @Raj: For starters, all documentation and examples are written in Java. None of the supported programming languages are familiar to me, except for JavaScript but I've never worked with node.js.

Comment: Selenium won't return status codes without some extra third party tools, so if you are only interested in that, Selenium is probably not your tool.

Comment: @Arran: Correct. None of the given requirements can be solved easily with any of the tools I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have succeeded in setting up unit testing using Mocha.

Website: http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/

**Problem 1: Checking the HTTP status**

I found an alternative for this: superagent
https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

This module allows you to perform basic HTTP requests and gives you all information you might expect. You can use this to check any kind of header (ie. check if you're getting JSON data when you set "accept-type: application/json" in your request)

```
    request
        .get('http://mywebsite/')
        .end(function (res) {
            assert.strictEqual(res.statusCode, 200);
            done();
        });
```

**Problem 2: Checking for missing files**

No working solution yet, but we're looking into node.js crawlers to get this done:
https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/crawling

**Problem 3: Checking for Javascript errors**

We now use a generic error handler (window.onerror) that will store all JS errors in a global variable. WebdriverJS (Selenium client written in Node.JS) allows you to inject JS to retrieve this information. This is our code:

```
    client
        .execute("return typeof window.errors", [], function (err, output) {
            assert.isNull(err);
            assert.strictEqual(output.value, "undefined");
        })
        .call(done);
```